# Strange issue, the element do not remove from list

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I want to use forloop to delete some element that meets the conditions.

```
name_list = ["Win-0.3.4-x86_64", "CentOS7.1"]

for name in name_list:
    if "snapshot" not in name:
        name_list.remove(name)

print name_list  # there print ['CentOS7.1']
```

But in the end, it do not delete all the elements that meet the condition.

Comment: Because, you modify the list in place, so the size shrinks. Don't do that.

Comment: A normal iteration won't be correct if you are modifying what you are iterating.

Comment: Removing items from a list that you're iterating over is like sawing off a tree branch that you're sitting on. If you saw on the wrong side Bad Things happen. ;) You _can_ safely remove items from a list if you iterate over it in reverse, but generally it's simpler to just iterate normally and build a new list.

Answer (score 0):

You can not forloop the list, and modify the list's element in place, the iterating will not normal execute.

You can copy the list to a new list, then forloop the new list, and remove the origin list.

You try to use bellow code:

```
import copy

name_list = ["Win-0.3.4-x86_64", "CentOS7.1"]

name_list_cp = copy.copy(name_list)

for name in name_list_cp:
    if "snapshot" not in name:
        name_list.remove(name)


print name_list
```

In the end, will print a empty list `[]`.